# Maintenance releases of mac application

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We are working on a Xamarin Mac application.
As  my knowledge we can distribute the installer (.dmg) to the users using following ways.

1.We can host the installer file from server  and user can download the installer from the server.

2.We can  submit the installer  to the AppStore, So that user  can download it from App store after the approval of Apple.

Is there any other way to distribute the xamarin mac application please let me know.

In future we need to  add additional features to the application as well as we may be need to made bug fixes  for the application if we face any bugs.

My question is how we will handle the version management ? We have to notify the end users if we launch any new version/Bug fixes. Also we need to provide the option for user to check whether any updates for this application comes.

How we will handle this? Is there any frame work for this?

Please let me know a way to manage version’s.

Any help would be appreciable.

Best Regards,

Ranish